# Can't find scodec-akka published to Maven Central

Tags: scala, maven, akka, scodec

I need to convert the ByteString received by AKKA Streams  to BitVector int order to decode it by scodec.
The library is said to be be published to Maven central under org.scodec %% scodec-akka as mentioned here [GitHub scodec-akka](https://github.com/scodec/scodec-akka)

so i need to know of the library was removed or i still can get it in some way. if not is there any work arround to make this conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scodec-akka library hasn't been published yet. We were holding off until we had some amount of support for akka-streams, but we could publish a version with just the `ByteVector` conversions.

Comment: Thnx for your quick response !
i would be so happy if it will be published soon as um in serious need for it to finish my graduation project efficiently :)
so should i wait for it or you suggest going for the copying solution till it is published?

Comment: I published 0.1.0 just now so you should be all set. Use "org.scodec" %% "scodec-akka" % "0.1.0". It is only built for scodec-core 1.9.0 + akka 2.4. Also, feel free to drop in to https://gitter.im/scodec/scodec and let us know about your graduation project and how you like scodec!